# Display Common attributes for selected categories?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom-options

How can i show my attributes for my selected categories, actually its common attribute like **Manufacture**?

Note: if i remove from attributes set it is not displayed for my remaining categories,

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you explain more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Eg: My attribute name: height, i have 10 categories, height attribute only for Idols, not Books, But i need height attributes for my books category also for backend purpose. is clear?

Comment: attribute are shown based on attribute sets, so if you want to show any attribute for a product, you have to assign that attribute to the attribute set you have chosen for the product

Comment: Yes, You are right. explain me how can I enter "height" attribute for my book, one condition height attribute not display in the front end, make sure height attribute display in another category.

Comment: @Piyush no, still not working,,

Comment: For me it's still not clear what your asking for ... ca you please update your question?

Answer (score 0):

To Assign your attribute (`height`) to any Attribute set, follow the path: **Catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attribute Sets**. Click on attribute set you want to assign the attribute `height`  and a configuration page is opened. In this page you have to move `height` from  unassigned attribute tab to left tab under any attribute group  and save the attribute set.

Check detailed information [here](https://amasty.com/blog/beginners-guide-on-magento-product-attribute-sets/)

### **Update from Comments**

In attribute edit page you can choose whether to display attribute in frontend by setting yes/no to **Visible on Product View Page on Front-end** , But it will apply to all products, there is no configuration in admin to display it for a particular category and hide on others.

If you want to display the attribute for only a particular category you can try below suggestions-

1. You can add category based condition to display attribute in code.
2. You can create separate attribute for books category and set no to
   display in frontend.

For the first option you have to override template -

> app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

And add condition for particular category and attribute code.

Comment: How can i add height attribute values to my book, mind that if i need to enter attribute values it must be under the attribute set, but if the attribute under attribute set is should be displayed on website front end, my primary condition height attribute values display only for idols, not book category.

Comment: I hope now you understand clearly.

Comment: In attribute edit page you can choose whether to display attribute in frontend by  setting `yes/no` to `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` , But it will apply to all products, there is no configuration in admin to display it for a particular category and hide on others

Comment: You rock, finally, you got my point...  Are any other possibilities exist?

Comment: Yes there are two ways, 1- you can add category based condition to display attribute in code, 2. - you can create separate attribute for books category and set no to display  in frontend

Comment: I won't recommend the second way actually

Comment: How can i do it first condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72385/discussion-between-zus-and-piyush).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily from admin without any coding, but this might be tricky if you already have a lot of products in your shop.

I propose you create 2x height attributes, for example `height` and `height_books` assign each of them to their own attribute sets, for example attribute set **Idols** and attribute set **Books**.

Then you can show the `height` attribute on Frontend, but hide the `height_books` attribute.

If this is not an option (for whatever reason), you can do it with code in `/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml` if you want to do this on the Product View page.

First get the categoryIds, then check if the product belongs to your category. For example, if you don't want to show the height attribute for `books` then check the Books category ID in admin->Catalog->Categories-> You can see the category ID when you select the category.

```
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$isBook = in_array(123, $categoryIds);
```

Then inside the foreach loop insert an if statements to check if the product belongs to the "not desired" category and if the attribute = `height`.

Basically you show the height on some categories and hide it for others:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php if ($_data['code'] == 'height') { ?>
        <?php if (!$isBook) { ?>            
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are asking to display a product attribute on product view page if yes then you simply have to go to Magento Admin-> Catalog ->Attribute and then manage attribute search your required attribute and set the value visible on frontend to yes here is a screenshot
http://prntscr.com/i7la33

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to specify which categories show individual attributes as filters, instead of having all `attributes` with option `use in layered navigation` enabled show on all categories.

The only way I've seen this done without heavy code changes is with [Amasty's Improved Layered Navigation extension](https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html). This effectively replaces the default layered navigation you'll see in the category left/right panels and comes with a lot of great options, including the one mentioned in your question.

You will still need to configure any attribute you wish to use in layered navigation as such, but then turn to the Amasty extension settings to specify per attribute which category they will be seen in. When I last used it, you can do an "include" or "exclude" rule by category IDs.

I hope this helps and gets the feature you are looking for running on your site.